# Django REST test ignores factory's url

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework

I have a weird error writing a APITestCase for a Django REST view.

This is my code:

```
class CreateUserTest(APITestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.superuser = User.objects.create_superuser('vishnu@vishnu.com', '1989-10-06', 'vishnupassword')
        self.client.login(username='vishnu', password='vishnupassword')
        self.data = a bunch of trivial data

    def test_can_create_user(self):
        print "create user"
        self.setup()
        self.token = Token.objects.get(user_id=self.superuser.id)
        self.api_key = settings.API_KEY
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.request = self.factory.post('/api/v1/uaaaaaasers/?api_key=%s' % self.api_key,
                                    self.data,
                                    HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token {}'.format(self.token))
        force_authenticate(self.request, user=self.superuser)
        self.view = UserList.as_view()
        self.response = self.view(self.request)
        self.response.render()
        #print self.response.content
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

As you see I run a factory.post to an intentionally wrong url /api/v1/uaaaaaasers/

But the test doesnt complain:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'... 
create user .
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Ran 1 test in 0.199s

OK Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Shouldnt it crash with that wrong url? How do I know the test is going fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing it all wrong... 
The response that you have tested is from the direct view call...

```
self.view = UserList.as_view()
self.response = self.view(self.request)
self.response.render()
    #print self.response.content
self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

your above case will always call the view...

In actual testcases we hit the urls with the client and test that response

```
self.response = self.client.post('/api/v1/uaaaaaasers/?api_key=%s' % self.api_key,
                                self.data,
                                HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token {}'.format(self.token))
self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Where are you getting the self.response from in your example?

Comment: @lapinkoira updated above :)... the issue in your above code is just that django is not mapping the url to the view... You are manually calling the view :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test posting a request to an invalid url, use the [test client](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#example) instead of the request factory.

```
class CreateUserTest(APITestCase):

    def test_can_create_user(self):
       ...
       response = self.client.post(
           '/api/v1/uaaaaaasers/?api_key=%s' % self.api_key,
           self.data,
           ...
       )
       ...
```

Comment: mmm I am confused here, how do I know I didnt misspell my urls in all my tests for example? cant I rely on request factory? or how are the best practises for testing api views in django rest?

Comment: If you use request factory, you are testing the view. You are not testing that your url pattern is configured with the correct view. Using the test client simulates a request to a particular url, so *is* testing your url config. The request factory gives you more control, but a lot of the time this is not necessary, and it's easier to use the test client.